# Selecting a column with a dot in R (nested object)

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I'm not sure how to rephrase the question, but basically, I have this dataset coming from the following code:

```
data_url <- 'https://prod-scores-api.ausopen.com/year/2021/stats'
dat <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data_url)
men_aces <- bind_rows(dat$statistics$rankings[[1]]$players[1])
men_aces_table <- dat$players %>%
     inner_join(men_aces, by = c('uuid' = 'player_id')) %>% select(full_name, nationality)
```

Which resulted in this data frame:

```
               full_name                     nationality.uuid         nationality.name nationality.code
1         Novak Djokovic 99da9b29-eade-4ac3-a7b0-b0b8c2192df7                   Serbia              SRB
2       Alexander Zverev 99d83e85-3173-4ccc-9d91-8368720f4a47                  Germany              GER
3           Milos Raonic 07779acb-6740-4b26-a664-f01c0b54b390                   Canada              CAN
4        Daniil Medvedev fa925d2d-337f-4074-a0bd-afddb38d66e1                   Russia              RUS
5           Nick Kyrgios 9b11f78c-47c1-43c4-97d0-ba3381eb9f07                Australia              AUS
```

[image: Desc]
`nationality` is the nested object inside the player object if you check the JSON url, it contains the above properties (uuid, name, code), if I select the `full_name` property I would get the value (which is of type character) right back.

I'm not sure how to select the `name` and from that data frame (nationality) and rename it to `country`.

My expected outcome is:

```
           full_name                       country
1         Novak Djokovic                   Serbia              
2       Alexander Zverev                   Germany              
3           Milos Raonic                   Canada              
4        Daniil Medvedev                   Russia              
5         Nick Kyrgios                    Australia
```

I would appreciate some help. Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: do you just need `dat$players$full_name` or `dat$players$nationality$name
`?

Comment: I changed my question a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `purrr::pmap_chr`

```
library(tidyverse)

dat$players %>%
  inner_join(men_aces, by = c('uuid' = 'player_id')) %>%
  select(full_name, nationality) %>%
  mutate(nationality = pmap_chr(nationality, ~ ..2))

               full_name              nationality
1         Novak Djokovic                   Serbia
2       Alexander Zverev                  Germany
3           Milos Raonic                   Canada
4        Daniil Medvedev                   Russia
5           Nick Kyrgios                Australia
6       Alexander Bublik               Kazakhstan
7          Reilly Opelka United States of America
8            Jiri Vesely           Czech Republic
9          Andrey Rublev                   Russia
10          Lloyd Harris             South Africa
11        Aslan Karatsev                   Russia
12          Taylor Fritz United States of America
13     Matteo Berrettini                    Italy
14       Grigor Dimitrov                 Bulgaria
15       Feliciano Lopez                    Spain
16    Stefanos Tsitsipas                   Greece
17 Felix Auger-Aliassime                   Canada
18    Thanasi Kokkinakis                Australia
19           Ugo Humbert                   France
20           Borna Coric                  Croatia
```

Comment: I changed my question a bit and said my expected outcome.

Comment: see edit.  I used `pmap_chr` from `purrr` to extract second column (..2) from nationality object

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

`bind_cols(full_name = dat$players$full_name, country = dat$players$nationality$name)`

```
# A tibble: 169 x 2
   full_name        country                 
   <chr>            <chr>                   
 1 Novak Djokovic   Serbia                  
 2 Alexander Zverev Germany                 
 3 Milos Raonic     Canada                  
 4 Daniil Medvedev  Russia                  
 5 Nick Kyrgios     Australia               
 6 Alexander Bublik Kazakhstan              
 7 Reilly Opelka    United States of America
 8 Jiri Vesely      Czech Republic          
 9 Andrey Rublev    Russia                  
10 Lloyd Harris     South Africa
```

Answer (score 1):

just add this line at the end

```
newdf <- data.frame(full_name = men_aces_table$full_name, country = men_aces_table$nationality$name)
```